# How to get number of days since midnight UT as January 1 begins in python?

Tags: python, date, time, calendar, astronomy

I want to program a Python function that calculates the current solar declination by using this formula on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun. The formula requires knowing the number of days since midnight UT as January 1 begins. Is there a way to get this in Python?

Here is what the Wikipedia page says is needed for the formula's variable N:
N is the number of days since midnight UT as January 1 begins (i.e. the days part of the ordinal date −1) and can include decimals to adjust for local times later or earlier in the day.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this as I'm still learning with `datetime`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Yes, you can do this with Python, but your question sounds like you want us to do your homework for you. Such questions generally don't do well here; see [ask]. Your best bet is to write some code and get started, and then post here with specific problems you ran into.